# Wrap every word in double quotes but ignore the word(s) which is already wrapped in double quotes, using regex

Tags: regex, python-re

I have a query in which I want to wrap every word in double quotes by ignoring certain attributes, but I also want to ignore the words which are already in double quotes.

I am ignoring has, from, to, sample etc but not able to ignore words in double quotes.

Could anyone please nudge me in the right direction ?

Current regex -

> \b(?!\bOR\b)\b(?!\bAND\b)\b(?!\bfrom:\b)\b(?!\bto:\b)\b(?!\bhas:\b)\b(?!\bsample\b)\w+\b

Query -

> (@harrys OR from:harrys OR to:harrys OR ("harry's" OR harrys) AND
> (razor OR razors OR shave OR shaving OR shaved OR shaver OR
> subscription OR razorhead OR razorheads OR buy OR bought OR buying OR
> boxers OR cover) AND (has:geo OR has:profile_geo)  -styles -prince
> -markle -meghanmarkle)

Answer (score 1):

You can match and capture all your exceptions, and just match your expected matches, then, when replacing, check if Group 1 participated in the match, and replace accordingly.

Here is what I mean:

```py
import re
text = r"""(@harrys OR from:harrys OR to:harrys OR ("harry's" OR harrys) AND (razor OR razors OR shave OR shaving OR shaved OR shaver OR subscription OR razorhead OR razorheads OR buy OR bought OR buying OR boxers OR cover) AND (has:geo OR has:profile_geo) -styles -prince -markle -meghanmarkle)"""
pattern = r'("[^"]*"|\b(?:(?:OR|AND|sample)\b|(?:from|to|has):))|\w+'
print( re.sub(pattern, lambda m: f'"{m.group(1)}"' if m.group(1) else m.group(), text) )
```

Output:

```
(@harrys "OR" "from:"harrys "OR" "to:"harrys "OR" (""harry's"" "OR" harrys) "AND" (razor "OR" razors "OR" shave "OR" shaving "OR" shaved "OR" shaver "OR" subscription "OR" razorhead "OR" razorheads "OR" buy "OR" bought "OR" buying "OR" boxers "OR" cover) "AND" ("has:"geo "OR" "has:"profile_geo) -styles -prince -markle -mehanmarkle)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/yrKlzg). See also the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jbLJRi/1) (all green matches are kept, all blue matches are enclosed with double quotes).

*Regex details*:

- `("[^"]*"|\b(?:(?:OR|AND|sample)\b|(?:from|to|has):))` - Group 1 (this text is kept as is, exceptions):

  - `"[^"]*"` - `"`, zero or more chars other than `"`, and a `"` char
  - `|` - or
  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `(?:` - start of the non-capturing group

    - `(?:OR|AND|sample)\b` - `OR`, `AND`, `sample` and a word boundary
    - `|` - or
    - `(?:from|to|has):` - `from`, `to`, `has` and a colon
  - `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `|` - or
- `\w+` - one or more word chars.

Comment: Thanks @wiktor for your help, it works but however when I pass spider-man to this code, it wraps spider and man both in double quotes. like "spider"-"man"; ideally it should have taken it as a one term - "spider-man". Could you please suggest what should I add in this code to do this ? Also if i pass #spiderman it comes as #"spiderman" how can I include hashtag also in double quotes ?

Comment: @Ezio Replace the last `\w+` with `[^\s()]+`. Or, if the leading hyphen must be left out, `[^\s()-][^\s()]*`